# Toggle animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this code:

```
$('.couch-hide').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({right:0},1000, 'easeOutBounce');           
});
```

I am trying to get it to toggle, so on first click, pop it out, then click again, and place it back inside. Would i need to set a variable as a tracker? To tell what stage it is at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just save the original value somewhere, and remember to stop any in-progress animation before starting a new one. The animation routines will take care of the rest:

```
var panel = $('.couch-hide');
var originalPos = panel.css("right");
panel.toggle(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({right:0},1000, 'easeOutBounce');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({right:originalPos},1000, 'easeOutBounce');
  });
```

Comment: I didnt know that toggle can work like that with anything. I will keep this in mind.  This is VERY handy. Thanks for this. Why do you have the stop() in there?

Comment: @Coughlin: The call to stop() is there just make certain that I don't accidentally have two conflicting animations going at once (say, because you double-clicked the panel).

Answer (score 0):

Generally jquery toggle works pretty much in a standard way as given below, however i have not really tried it with animation stuff but this may work.

```
$('.couch-hide').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({right:0},1000, 'easeOutBounce').toggle();                       
});
```