# How to use the function .toggle?

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate

How to make a reversing animation with `.animate`?
I read in others places about the function `.toggle`, however when i used it, this function starts automatically without the "click". I want it (the function) begins only when I (or the user) click it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dae").toggle(
        function(){
            $("#dae").click(function(){
                $("#dae").animate({left:'50px', top:'100px'}, "slow");
                $("#dae").animate({opacity:0.1}, "slow");
                $("#dae").animate({opacity:1.0}, "slow");
            });
        }, function(){
            $("#dae").click(function(){
                $("#dae").animate({opacity:1.0}, "slow");
                $("#dae").animate({opacity:0.1}, "slow");
                $("#dae").animate({left:'10px', top:'20px'}, "slow");
            });
        }
    )
});
```

The problem is: when the browser starts, the `div` disappears.

Comment: Try this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794912/toggle-animation

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the "click" event in the toggle. .toggle() is based on the click event.

So set it up as such:

```
$("#dae").toggle(
    function(){

            $(this).animate({left:'50px', top:'100px'}, "slow");
            $(this).animate({opacity:0.1}, "slow");
            $(this).animate({opacity:1.0}, "slow");

    }, function(){

            $(this).animate({opacity:1.0}, "slow");
            $(this).animate({opacity:0.1}, "slow");
            $(this).animate({left:'10px', top:'20px'}, "slow");

    }
)
```

Try the above and see how that works for you. let me know if u have any issues.

Edit: Note as posted below this will not work in newer ver. of jquery as it no longer supports both functions. good and valid point.

Comment: I make this, but nothing happnes with the div "dae" when i click on it... What can be?

Comment: I'll create a jsfiddle for u just a min.

Comment: @TopGear3000 You need to take a different approach probably, see my answer.

Comment: let's clarify this. because I have it working but this can't be what you want. as it will toggle but the animation the way you have it defined just hides it. as in explain each step page load what happens. they click then what happens etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

I am not sure which jquery version you are using, but [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) no longer takes 2 callbacks. Also you need to do it on click rather that executing toggle which is why you see it getting executed initially itself.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EgzYj/)

```
$("#dae").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is('.animate')) //Just add this class to detect the state.
    {
       
            $this.animate({left:'50px', top:'100px'}, "slow")
             .animate({opacity:0.1}, "slow")
             .animate({opacity:1.0}, "slow");
     }
    else
    {
         $this.animate({opacity:1.0}, "slow")
         .animate({opacity:0.1}, "slow")
         .animate({left:'10px', top:'20px'}, "slow");
    }
   $this.toggleClass('animate'); //add/remove class based on its previous state.
});
```

Comment: +1 @PSL on the multi callbacks. He posted both so I made the assumption probably shouldn't' have. you could also do this as PSL has noted with a click event using data() also would work just fine if you don't want to use a class.

Comment: Another thing is that toggle no longer supports multi-callbacks so even if OP is using an older version of Jquery once he upgrades it it will fail. So it needs to be handled manually. I did not get your +1 though :)

Comment: just tested it, it works in say 1.6, regardless he should change the design altogether.